# bindActionCreators is not producing a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am connecting my component, and binding my actionCreators. This is a similar pattern I have taken on a component that works. I am using a react-table to call my click event, but I am calling my redux action outside of the table, to try to not have any interference. Here is my component's code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {goToBook} from '../actions/index';

export class RoutingDnD extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        };

        this.onPassBook = this.onPassBook.bind(this);
    }

    onPassBook(val){
        this.props.goToBook(val, this.props.history);
    }

    render() {
        if(!this.props.routingBooks ){
            return <div>Books not loaded</div>;
        }
console.log(this.props.goToBook)
        return (
            <div>
            <ReactTable
                data={this.props.routingBooks}
                showPagination={false}
                sortable= {true}
                multiSort={true}
                getTrProps={( state, rowInfo, column, instance) => ({
                    onClick: e => {
                        this.onPassBook(rowInfo.row['base.ItemKey']);
                    }
                })}
                columns={[
                    all of my column code was here...]}

                SubComponent={row => {
                    return (
                        <div style={{ padding: "5px" }}>

                            <ReactTable
                                data={row.original.inventory.warehouses}
                                defaultPageSize={row.original.inventory.warehouses.length}
                                columns={[
                                    ...more column code
                                ]}
                                showPagination={false}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                }}

                defaultSorted={[
                    {
                        id: "Title",
                        desc: true
                    }
                ]}
                className="-striped -highlight"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        goToBook: bindActionCreators(goToBook, dispatch)
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        routing: state.activeRouting,
        routingBooks: state.routingBooks
    };
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RoutingDnD))
```

It appears my goToBook function always returns undefined:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.goToBook is not a function
>       at RoutingDnD.onPassBook (bundle.js:42656)
>       at onClick (bundle.js:42457)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:65435)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:65474)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:65331)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (bundle.js:65345)
>       at executeDispatch (bundle.js:65729)
>       at executeDispatchesInOrder (bundle.js:65748)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (bundle.js:65849)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (bundle.js:65860)

I am not sure why, I have mapDispatchToProps called in connect, I am importing my goToBook action, and I am binding it with bindActionCreators.

Here is my calls in my actions/index.js:

```
export const GO_TO_BOOK = 'GO_TO_BOOK';
export function goToBook(book, history) {
    history.push(`/bis/landing/book/${book}`);
    return {
        type: GO_TO_BOOK,
        payload: book

    }
}
```

And my reducer:

```
import {GO_TO_ROUTING} from "../actions/index";

const defaultState = {
    routingID:0,
    versionID: 0
};
export default function(state = defaultState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GO_TO_ROUTING:
            return {...state, routingID: action.payload.routingID, versionID: action.payload.versionID};
    }
    return state
}
```

Comment: did you `console.log` what goToBook is? It may be nested under another key, normally you would use bindActionCreators to bind an export with multiple keys see docs - https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators - for an example

Comment: goToBook is console.logging undefined.

Comment: try this `goToBook: bindActionCreators( { goToBook }, dispatch)`

Comment: There's no need to use binActionCreators, you can just return a plain object like this `mapDispatchToProps = { goToBook };`. Done.

Comment: @DominicTobias I know that is a possibility but the problem was nested connected components and the child for some reason couldn't use bindActionCreators, but it could have it passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by taking this bindActionCreator and putting it into my parent. Then I passed this function into my child component and it worked. 
Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I also moved the withRouter out of the child and just passed data from my child up to the parent, and let the parent handle the bindActionCreator. This totally worked. Both bindActionCreators and withRouter failed in the child.

> The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some
>   action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you
>   don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it

This was in your link @Eric Hasselbring. Much thanks.